# Jaspersoft Studio: How I can remove empty table footer on the top of next site?

Tags: layout

Jaspersoft Studio (Community Version) generates sometimes an empty tablefooter at the start of the 
following page (looking on current), if not enought place at the current.
How I can avoid this - maybe with some print-then-expression?

To get easier understood and fix the issue I've uploaded some 
examplefiles to https://github.com/dura4cell/FooterProblem

You can download the files and import the dataadapter to test it.

(After importing the DataAdapter you must only fix the path to the xml-file ;-):-)

**INSTRUCTIONS FOR REPRODUCING THE PROBLEM**

1. Download following parts from GIT https://github.com/dura4cell/FooterProblem:

   - Layoutfile
   - XML
   - Dataadapter
2. Create new project an put all files into
3. Import Data Adapter
4. Update path of Data Adapter to your local project

Regards
Peter